# One to Many relationship in Laravel Eloquent giving undefine method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am having the said problem when defining one to many relationship with two models, the Student and Enrollment. When accessing the table from another table using:

```
$enrollment = App\Enrollment::first();
$enrollment->students()->first_name;
```

Im getting :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students.enrollment_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `students` where `students`.`enrollment_id` = 1 and `students`.`enrollment_id` is not null)'
```

However when I use :

```
 $enrollment = App\Enrollment::first();
 $enrollment->students()->first_name;
```

Im getting :

```
PHP error:  Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$first_name on line 1
```

Can someone help me on this?

Enrollment

```
protected $fillable = [
    'subject_code',
    'subject_description',
    'section',
    'schedule',
    'room_no',
    'no_of_units'
];

public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
}
```

Student

```
protected $fillable = [
    'enrollments_id',
    'student_no',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'middle_name',
    'birthdate',
    'fathers_name',
    'mothers_name',
    'phone_no',
    'degree_id',
    'city_id',
    'address'
];

public function enrollment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Enrollment');
}
```

Here's the table for the students and enrollment accordingly

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('enrollments_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('student_no');

            $table->foreign('enrollments_id')->references('id')->on('enrollments')->unsigned();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('middle_name');
            $table->date('birthdate');
            $table->string('fathers_name');
            $table->string('mothers_name');
            $table->string('phone_no');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->integer('city_id');
            $table->integer('degree_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
Schema::create('enrollments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('subject_description');
        $table->string('subject_code');
        $table->time('schedule');
        $table->string('room_no');
        $table->integer('no_of_units');
        $table->string('section');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you exactly want 
as per your question i am assuming you want 'enrollment has many students', for this relationship you need enrolment_id in students table not student_id in enrollment table.
and after that use

```
$students= Enrolment::find(id)->students;
```

it will return all students with the required enrollment id

Comment: It seems your wrong since enrollment has many enrollees or students right?

Comment: since enrollment has many students, you need to have enrolment_id in students table, else how will you know which student belongs to which enrollment..

Comment: Okay got your point. Thanks. Now I messed with my tables I change values and deleted my migrations. How will I migrate one table at a time? thanks.

Comment: and also if you want 'enrollment has many students' then you dont need student_id in enrollment table

Comment: try this,php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/temp, copy your migration file to temp folder

Comment: Do I need to make the enrollment_id as foreign key in student's table?

Comment: I updated my question with the solutions you provided. However there are still error. Kindly check updated problem.

Comment: in your student table you have created enrollments_id and as per laravel convention it should be enrollment_id, but as for now just add
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Enrollment', enrollments_id);

Comment: and in migrations there is no need for  $table->foreign('enrollments_id')->references('id')->on('enrollments')->unsigned(); only "  $table->integer('enrollments_id')->unsigned();" will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

That normal since you're trying to get property `first_name` from `hasMany` object, you should use `get()` method if you want to get `Collection` of objects (in your case collection of `students`) :

```
$enrollment->students()->get();
```

And if you want to get the first name you should specify the object you want to get the `first_name` from it, e.g :

```
$enrollment->students()->first()->first_name;
$enrollment->students()->last()->first_name;
```

If you want to get the attribute `first_name` of all the `students` you should use `lists` method, e.g :

```
$enrollment->students()->lists('first_name');
```

Output: collection of all students first names.

Hope this helps.

---

**Update :**
Try to remove `->unsigned()` in :

```
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
```

and also in :

```
$table->foreign('enrollments_id')->references('id')->on('enrollments')->unsigned();
```

Comment: Tahnk you but Im getting an empty object  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#709
     all: [],
   }

Comment: Still the same empty array,

Comment: You should remigrate after changes. and make sure that you have already some students attached to the enrollment.

Comment: Acharki Do I need to use the attach() method? I thought that's for pivot (many to many) relationship only?

Comment: You should use `associate()` in your case `$enrollment->students()->associate($student);`.

Comment: $enrollment->students()->get(); or $enrollment->students

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki Do not use associate in one to many since it will automatically declare upon using belongsTo and associating two tables by using foreign key.

Comment: @Mike Miller What if I only want to retrieve the name of the student $enrollment->student->lists('first_name') can I use this?

Comment: You are getting a collection so you cant get an attribute of the student without saying which one you want. I would make a scope to pass in a student id or name or whatever makes sense and return a single student

Answer (score 0):

When you call relations on an eloquent object it actually return you the relation not the exact objects

for eg: in your case 
$enrollment->students() will return the relation 
where as
$enrollment->students will return the eloquent object ( in belongs to, has one relations ) and collection/array of eloquent object/objects(in one to many , many to many relations )

simply  if you are using it as an attribute you will get the actual result and relation query if it is called as a function

even if you get the relation you can get the results by calling get on top of that

$enrollment->students()->get()